# Refreshing a GLUT window

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, glut

Please, excuse my bad english.

I'm developing a program with OpenGL, GLUT and C++ that moves a block of polygons around the window. Well, first I used the GLUT timer function and it works fine. Now, I want to implement my own timer, so I wrote one. But when I use it in the same file, the animation works so slow. The timer create a thread to execute the function to move the block and I think the problem is that glutPostRedisplay don't refresh automatically the window and the timer continues doing calls to these function without consider if the winow was really updated or not.

My question is, is this the problem? How can solve it?

If is necesary, I can post the code, but is so large and hard to read...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

glutPostRedisplay only sets the flag that means window needs to be updated, update will happen after glutSwapBuffers.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using freeglut, so finally I added the function glutLeaveMainLoop to force the refresh.